# Boost uses same thread for different operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am writing a server which will reply to each client via a new thread.

Server Code :

```
void ThreadB_Activity(ClientDetails ReplytoThis)
{
    cout<<endl<<"In thread with Id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<endl;
    Mutex.lock();
    /* Perform replying activities */
    Mutex.unlock();
}

void OnRequestOne(ClientDetails Requestor, std::string data)
{
    cout<<endl<<"Got data in request one as : "<<data;
    boost::thread ThreadB(&ReplySocketTest::ThreadB_Activity,this,Requestor);    
}
```

OnRequestOne will be triggered whenever a request comes up. Currently am testing with 140 clients firing requests every 1 second.

The server is able to reply to all of the clients but I am getting the same thread id for 80% of the replies. How does Boost do this?

Sample Output : 
Serverd request no :316714

Got data in request one as : Request-One
In thread with Id : **0xa78830**

Serverd request no :316715

Got data in request one as : Request-One
In thread with Id : **0xa78830**

Comment: Are you sure there is at least two simultaneous requests at one time ? if the server is able to process a request before another arrive, the spawning thread might use the same id. Try logging time for thread creation/deletion to see if you really are in a multithreading env.

Comment: Yes, the clients are firing requests simultaneously. I just want to know if this is normal. Means it is designed to create and destroy n threads for n requests received. And it is not working as per design.

Comment: How does your server receive the input? boost::asio? What have you done to verify that the requests are indeed simultaneously received on the server? Try to make request processing more expensive/take longer and see what happens.

Comment: BTW, note that your code will work only with quite outdated `Boost.Thread` versions, which are not std complient. With more recent versions `OnRequestOne` would crash, because you do not call `ThreadB.detach()` before exiting the function.

Comment: @Hulk The request is coming through a zmq socket. I have added a delay in replying and now I can observe an average of 88 threads operational which seems fine for the functionality.  So does this mean if there is no delay in responding boost releases the thread and again catches the same one? Sounds bit impractical. Please give your views on this.

Comment: @Igor : I have tried using detach earlier. But still the same. 3 threads spawned and used for all the requests.

Comment: I guess that without artificial delay your request processing is fast enough to complete before the next request is received. It is quite possible that the next spawning thread just gets the same thread id. In such a scenario, you may want to eliminate the overhead of thread creation by using a thread pool or by using a single-threaded asynchronous approach (futures etc)

Comment: @Hulk sure I will try to use a threadpool and investigate. Thanks for the help.